# program run by browser

Tags: windows, browser

I have to write program in C++ to find file on the disc, rename it unpack (because it's ZIP) and run MS Excel to show unpacked .xls content. Easy, I write this program (lets say “test.exe”) quickly and tested on my laptop. Program is working, fine.

But when I tried to run it via browser (this zip file is coming from server and I download it to my disk) I found some problems:

- on Firefox I can download file or open via pointed application; when I choose my text.exe everything is the same excepting my program “test.exe” can’t delete file;
- on Opera or Explorer situation is worst – I download file to disk (my directory) and I see this downloaded file on this place but no operation of “test.exe” is correct, I can’t rename, copy or delete file, even test operation FileExist() (checking if file exist in the directory on the disk) return false but when I check manually, path and the name of this file is correct.

What should I know to correct my working (as a single application) program?

Comment: Do you have Show File Extensions enabled in Explorer? What is the output of `dir /a`?

Comment: I don't know "Show File Extensions" but I don't want to use windows progtram. I choose my program to handle downloaded file. And as I said - FireFox working good but can't delete file in the end. Opera, IE and Chrome can't even rename file to ".zip" because can't find this file. But I see this file in the download directory in Windows Expliorer and can do anything with it.